# Bold Top 50% of the summed values in Column E and their rows

Tags: excel, vba

After seeking help in stackoverflow, I came back with the skeleton of the vba codes (still not working though), however it is not generating the outcome that I desire.

```
Sub Highlight_Top50()

    Dim CheckRange As range

    Set CheckRange = range("E2:E", Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Row

    Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
    .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
    .Rank = 50
    .Percent = True
    End With

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font.Bold = True

    End With

    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

Under Conditional Formatting, there's no such rule as "Highlight **Top 50% of the summed value**". The nearest Excel provides is "Format cells that **rank** in Top: x%".

Answer (score 1):

You're close. There are a couple of problems to fix.

The first is to ALWAYS make sure you're specifying a worksheet reference. Notice in the code below there is a '.' before ***ALL*** of the sheet references. This ensures you're referencing the sheet in the `With` clause.

```
With ActiveSheet
    Set CheckRange = .Range("E2:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

Also, when you're counting the rows until the end of the data, the `.Row` was in the wrong place (outside of the `)`).

Next, you set up your `CheckRange` variable but you don't use it. You should avoid using `Select`. So just make the references for the `FormatConditions` to your `CheckRange`.

```
With CheckRange
    ...
End With
```

Here is the corrected method.

```
Sub Highlight_Top50()
    Dim CheckRange As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set CheckRange = .Range("E2:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    With CheckRange
        .FormatConditions.AddTop10
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
            .Rank = 50
            .Percent = True
            .Font.Bold = True
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. It worked flawlessly!

Comment: `Sub 
    With CheckRange
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="=0.5*SUM(E2:E)"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
` I modified the code with formula in order to obtain the top 50% of the summed value, however I got an error message "Invalid Procedure call or argument.. Not sure what went wrong this time.

Comment: Amended the cell range, the error message is now gone. But nothing is bolded. `.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="=0.5*SUM(E:E)"`

Comment: If I understand your formula correctly, you are summing all the values in column E, then you want to highlight the values in the same column that are greater than or equal to 50% of the summed value. By definition this condition will never be met. Say you have 50 values in column E, all between 1 and 10. The sum of those values will be somewhere between 50 and 500. Half or that is 25 to 250. If all the values are 10 or less, you'll never get a value even close to 25. So you'll never see your condition met. I think you need a different condition. Maybe try `AVERAGE`?